# How do I fix this loop python loop?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Basically I am trying to have the multiple names being set into my array. For example, I am getting user input and I want the first name to be set to name[0] and the next name the user enters to be assigned to name[1] and so on and so forth. Attached is the code that I have so far and was wondering if someone could help me with this small and easy project.

```
k = 0

while k < 10:
    name = []
    name[k] = input("enter: ")
    k += 1
```

Comment: There's no code attached at the moment, please include it as text instead of using a different format

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Could you please attach the code that you have prepared so far.

Comment: Your code recreates a new `name` empty list in each loop. Do it once before, and see `list.append` - you can't index a non-existing item, as you try to do with `name[k] = ...`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

if your user give all names with space separator like

> aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj

then

```
names = input().split(" ");
```

this code will works file.

But if user gives each input in new line then you can use any below mention methods:

first solution.

```
names = []
k=10
while k<5:
    names.append(input())
    k=k+1
print(names)
```

second solution.

```
names = []
k=10
for i in range(k):
    names.append(input())
print(names)
```